# Replace default text with custom text on spree default app 2.0.3

Tags: spree

Hi Spree guys' I am using spree 2.0.3 . I want to change the 'SHOP' text to 'Grab food' , 'Cart'-->'food cart' and in aside 'shop by categories',for this I want to replace with 'grab by categories'...Which view inside spree_frontend , i hv to modify..and how ?

Also for 'shop' text when i am doing right click to see eveything in dev tool i m getting:
 class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.spree.shop as properties and also shop is not there in config/en.yml....

I am able to change 'cart' to 'food-cart' by overriding view and for 'shop by' text to 'grab by' ..i am able to convert using config/en.yml...but i am not able to find view for 'shop' text.

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 5):

You can use the wonderful [xray-rails](https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails) gem in order to help figure out what content is coming from where.  Here's a sample from the spree sandbox:

[image: xray-rails sample]

As an example you can see that the cart link is provided in [_main_nav_bar.html.erb](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/views/spree/shared/_main_nav_bar.html.erb#L4) which uses the [link_to_cart](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/32416d1dbc44aee484685e457dc3553502751543/core/app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb#L15) helper which uses the [cart translation in en.yml](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/config/locales/en.yml#L372).

Try poking around and you should be able to find all of the translations you want to change and override them using the [Rails i18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) API.

Comment: Thanx man , In my case I have installed spree fancy gem too...and i am unable to find it in all views which identified by xray-rails gems...wen i used to right click 'shop 'than i saw it comes under list tag with id 'shop-link' but in all identified view no li with 'shop link' is dere...